# Is it compulsory to put semicolon after each statement

Tags: c++, syntax

Is there any difference between the following 2 codes

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    cout << i << endl,
    countSteps ++;
```

and

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        cout << i << endl;
        countSteps ++;
    }
```

Comment: Is there any relation between the question in the title and the question in the text?

Comment: One (the second) is readable and canonical, the other is not.

Comment: Using a comma operator instead of a semicolon to avoid adding wrapping the body in braces is a poor trade-off.  Other than that... it's a matter of convention.  And the prevalent convention throughout the industry is the second style, and avoiding the first style.

Comment: I agree the first version is more difficult to read while the second takes no effort at all to read and understand.

Answer (score 2):

The comma character has different meaning under different syntactic elements.

In your case, it is a comma operator.

For the sake clarity, the following does not constitute a statement.

```
cout << i << endl,
```

The following does.

```
cout << i << endl,
countSteps ++;
```

As does the following

```
cout << i << endl;
```

A semi-colon ends a statement. A comma does not.

For your posted code, the two blocks of code won't make any difference to the outcome of your program. However, it is good to know the difference between the syntactic constructs.

In general, they can have different behavior based on the value the expressions of the comma operator evaluate to. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator for additional details.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no difference in this case. (Except for the second snippet not looking ugly.)

In general case, `operator,` could be overloaded. Then the first option might can cause weird effects.